# User details being displayed in the browser dev tools

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a rails application where i am using javascript. Now when the user logsin inside the application i can see all the user details(email,pw,phone etc.) in the Network->Preview section of the browser dev tools. Is there a way to hide it in rails? so that when i open the browser dev tools i dont see the user details. I am using React js in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could understand, this is an authorization issue. You probably want to have different roles for your users and, based on such roles, decide what to display.

You may use **policies** to define which content each user is allowed to access. To this end, you could use the [pundit gem](https://github.com/varvet/pundit). It is very useful to define authorization mechanisms for controller actions.

If different users can access the same route but you need to hide some fields/details for some of them, you should pass the current_user to your serializations. For example, if you are using the [Active Model Serializers gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/), you need to add the current_user to the scope of your serializers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  serialization_scope :current_user
end
```

And then use that scope to display user details:

```
class UserSerializer < BaseSerializer
  attribute :name # Everyone can see
  attribute :email do # Only admins can see
    user = scope
    if user
      if user.admin?
        object.email
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[This article](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-authorization.html) have a deeper discussion regarding authorization in rails apps